# Express interface containing common properties of two tree-like objects in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types, interface, intersection

Let's say we have two interfaces `A` and `B`:

```
interface A {
   width: number;
   height: number;
   label: {
       text: string;
   };
   navigator: {
       min: number;
       max: number;
   }
}

interface B {
   width: number;
   height: number;
   label: {
       text: string;
       formatter: (text: string) => string;
   };
   radius: number;
}
```

I can specify the desired common shape manually like so:

```
interface AB {   // 
   width: number;
   height: number;
   label: {
       text: string;
   };
}
```

But ideally I would like the type system to figure out the shape automatically like so:

```
type AB = A & B; //
```

Obviously, `type AB` doesn't have the intended shape of `interface AB`.

Any ideas?

EDIT: An example use case:

```
const defaultTheme: AB = {
    common: { // default values for properties common to A and B
        width: 800,
        height: 400,
        label: {
            text: 'Title'
        }
    },
    A: { // missing defaults will come from `common`
        navigator: {
           min: 0,
           max: 1
        }
    },
    B: { // missing defaults will come from `common`
       label: {
           formatter: (text: string) => '$' + text
       },
       radius: 50
    }
};

// The user would configure a component in a declarative fashion:
const userConfig = {
    theme: defaultTheme,
    items: [{
        type: 'A',
        height: 600,
        navigator: {
            min: 0.5
        }
    }, {
        type: 'B',
        label: {
            text: 'My Custom Title'
        }
    }]
}
```

So the item properties not specified explicitly by the user will come from the default theme.

Comment: Doing that recursively (`label`) will be very tricky. If it's just the two, doesn't the intersection type do the job? You can use the common parts of the types without differentiating them, but you have each full type available if you do differentiate them (e.g., with a guard). What's the use case for a type `AB` that closes off that possibility?

Comment: [Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm4O7AAmYAFgFzIgCuAtgEbQDcOuJEwA5iWBdfUy2QAbOAyEVsuKbkgAPHsgDOYKKA7MpAXw24QcAG6c4YAPZQJg6TVC9aDKDunIacWbf4PBmrN6yhIsIgoAEKYggTE5JR2AlJsnNzu9o4iYhZOMhDyFMqqIOqWUjBmLmABFAAUcgq5agCUyAC8AHxKKmqO2oJQcITAVIpJAr5gAJ4ADiiooY1oyABkyMHMWDBUIAhgwCYgyFlwNONCEBVuaMENklIA9NfIFQCMdZYIO4omxwB0QiYcp58RUh1RgZZC3ZAAMVAEBebw+EG+v3+8S4YGBGXBUJAMOkrxA7y+Pz+sm+oggQk+1XRYLuWJhlnBFQATM9pMAYPcAER6QwcYxmTnIUDIWSXQo3O4VADMrNBeIJCKJ-x5RlMUE+1hA6Mx0Ms3jZHIqnJ6fQGguForCoJp9wALLKMvL4YjiaSxJ9ilBSgF-qlyZSsmjtbTddJvJogA).

Comment: I had to remove comments to make that fit in an SO comment, so: (1) = Using the common parts. (2) If and only if you need to use specific parts of A or B, you can once you've established what you have. (3) It's an A. (4). It's a B.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks. For example, if a library user wants to specify common properties that apply to all the objects in an array of items without having to merge those properties into every item's config. I would be nice if the type system could be used to guide the user as to what properties are going to valid for every item type.

Comment: That makes sense. I would usually approach it the other way: Define `AB`, then use `extends` to create `A` and `B`. [Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIICFkG8BQz8DuwAJmABYBcyIArgLYBG0A3HvmRMAOZlhW2MWbZABs4TEVVz4Z+SAA8+yAM5gooLqxkBfVtpw5QkWIhSpkERRBDFlaTNPwg4AN25wwAeyhThsuqD89ExQWrL4dHDyQYKhwvr6huDQ8EjImJaQNnYY2MJiEr7hcplUquogmn4yMN6RYMZUABQKSuUaAJTIALwAfCpqGmHIujj6QA). If you want to start from `A` and `B`, though, I think it's going to be complex... :-) (Don't know if that's really an *answer* to your question, so just leaving it as a comment. :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Haha, that's fair, I thought that might be the answer, but I had hope :) Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

You've given an example use in a comment explaining why `A & B` doesn't do what you want:

> For example, if a library user wants to specify common properties that apply to all the objects in an array of items without having to merge those properties into every item's config.

That makes sense. This isn't really an answer for how to get from `A` and `B` to `AB`, but FWIW I would usually approach this from the other direction: Define `AB`, then use `extends` to create `A` and `B`, like this:

```
interface AB {
   width: number;
   height: number;
   label: {
       text: string;
   };
}

interface A extends AB {
   navigator: {
       min: number;
       max: number;
   }
}

interface B extends AB {
   label: {
       text: string;
       formatter: (text: string) => string;
   };
}
```

I think trying to start from `A` and `B` and keeping only the common parts, particularly recursively (for `label`), will be really complex...